# customize length of lines vivagraph.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can customize length of lines [links] in vivagraph.js
there is a code like

```
graphics.link(function(link){
                return Viva.Graph.svg('path')
                           **.attr('length', 5);**

                           ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think length of the link is resulted from the layout of the graph. As far as I know you can set the layout using constant layout and calculating the node positions by yourself [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21676070/1926955) or set a global ideal link length (springLength) which is used while calculating the force directed layout as shown below.

```
var layout = Viva.Graph.Layout.forceDirected(graph, {
    springLength : 10
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example for custom lengths per link:

https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS/blob/master/demos/other/customLinkLength.html

I'll include excerpts -- It consists of adding custom data to each link,

```
graph.addLink(5, 6, { connectionStrength: 0.1 });
```

And then using that custom data to calculate the spring length using springTransform:

```
var idealLength = 90;
var layout = Viva.Graph.Layout.forceDirected(graph, {
               springLength: idealLength,
               springCoeff : 0.0008,
               gravity : -10,
               // This is the main part of this example. We are telling force directed
               // layout, that we want to change length of each physical spring
               // by overriding `springTransform` method:
               springTransform: function (link, spring) {
                    spring.length = idealLength * (1 - link.data.connectionStrength);
               }
});
```