# Circular layout in VivaGraphJS

Tags: javascript, layout, graph, graph-visualization

I'm using [VivaGraphJS](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS) to create my graph which is dynamic and keeps on updating as he data comes in. The problem is that [VivaGraph](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS) doesn't have the circular layout by default which I need.

I came across the [circular layout](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/be31f2a6525402b71e08d448dbd260f02b500377/src/extensions/cytoscape.layout.circle.js) in [cytoscape.js](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js) which I'd like to port to VivaGraph. I'm not able to completely understand what changes to make so as to have a port to VivaGraph. It'll be really appreciated if you could help me and guide me through it. Thanks :)

Also, here's an algorithm that I need since the number of crosses don't matter to me.

```
function CircularLayout(width, height)
{
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}

/**
 * Spreads the vertices evenly in a circle. No cross reduction.
 *
 * @param graph A valid graph instance
 */
CircularLayout.prototype.layout = function(graph)
{
  /* Radius. */
  var r = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2;

  /* Where to start the circle. */
  var dx = this.width / 2;
  var dy = this.height / 2;

  /* Calculate the step so that the vertices are equally apart. */
  var step = 2*Math.PI / graph.vertexCount; 
  var t = 0; // Start at "angle" 0.

  for (var i = 0; i<graph.vertices.length; i++) {
    var v = graph.vertices[i];
    v.x = Math.round(r*Math.cos(t) + dx);
    v.y = Math.round(r*Math.sin(t) + dy);
    t = t + step;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the constant layout and calculate the positions of the circular layout by yourself. code example below,

```
var gen = new Viva.Graph.generator();
var graph = gen.balancedBinTree(5);
var layout = Viva.Graph.Layout.constant(graph);
var nodePositions = generateNodePositions(graph,200);
layout.placeNode(function(node) { return nodePositions[node.id-1];});
renderer = Viva.Graph.View.renderer(graph,{ layout : layout });
renderer.run();
renderer.reset();
function generateNodePositions(graph,radius) {
    var nodePositions=[];
    var n = graph.getNodesCount();
    for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
        var pos = {
            x:radius*Math.cos(i*2*Math.PI/n),
            y:radius*Math.sin(i*2*Math.PI/n)
        }
        nodePositions.push(pos);
    }
    return nodePositions;
}
```